# How to Get Month Text In Arabic?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have This below query its working fine for Month Text in English but we need Month Text in Arabic How we do??I have Sql Server 2008R2.I have check using FORMAT function but its not work in 2008r2 edition.

```
DECLARE @tempdate TABLE 
  ( 
     pricedate DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     priceid   INT NOT NULL 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @tempdate 
            (pricedate, 
             priceid) 
SELECT pricelist_date, 
       pricelist_id 
FROM   vw_lu_region_and_date_list 
WHERE  price_status = '3' 
       AND region_id = '1' 
       AND saletype = '2' 
ORDER  BY pricelist_date DESC; 

WITH numbered 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, pricedate), 0 
                  ) 
                    ORDER BY pricedate DESC) AS rn 
         FROM   @tempdate) 
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), pricedate, 106), 8) AS PRICELIST_DATE, 
       priceid                                         AS PRICELIST_ID 
FROM   numbered 
WHERE  rn = 1 
ORDER  BY priceid DESC
```

I have get result from above query like

**Apr 2013**

**Mar 2013**

but we need like Apr and Mar in Arabic????

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to store as normal date and you can probably convert in your client application rather than in SQL.

In the organization I once worked for the previous developer designed a SQL CLR function to convert dates into Hebrew dates and return in Hebrew.
But You Can Use This :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnTranslateMonthNameToArabic
    (@date as datetime)
    RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result AS nvarchar(50);

    IF MONTH(@date) = 1
        SET @result = (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(2), DAY(@date)) + N' ' + N'يناير' + N' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(4), YEAR(@date)));
    IF MONTH(@date) = 2
        SET @result = N'and so on ...';

    RETURN @result;
END
Go


-- Test
SELECT dbo.fnTranslateMonthNameToArabic({d N'2012-01-16'}) AS Arabic
```

At Last Please Take a Look at [Arabic Language Support in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295829%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)